# IntelliJ doesn't update web resources when changed

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea

I have a JSF web app project (maven) and when i change something in a page, let's say a simple text inside the .xhtml page, the changes are not reflected to the deployed app, even if i manually update the classes and resources through the "run" command. (I am deploying the exploded war which i know is the only way for this to work). This happens while running and also debugging.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Have you enabled "make project automatically" in the compiler preferences?  You might also look at enabling the "compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running" registry setting in IntelliJ.  This has worked for me with resources in `src/main/resources`, on a non JSF project.

Comment: So it works if you use an .html file instead of an .xhtml file? If not, it is not JSF related

Comment: @Patrick Grimard It didn't work either way, tired to enable these two options but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was not IntelliJ's fault, turns out that somebody messed up server.xml in the conf folder of tomcat installation, and deactivated the parameter which made resources auto-update possible. Sadly i don't know exactly what was the right parameter, so i just downloaded tomcat again.